# Личные сообщения между пользователями сайта

Tags: база-данных, php, html, mysql

Вот скрипт личных сообщений между пользователями. Такая проблема: есть таблица mail и members. Почему при отправке сообщения получается передавать только name, lastname или username из таблицы пользователей (members) в таблицу сообщений (mail)?

Почему нельзя передавать данные $avatar из таблицы members, в таблицу mail в $avatar. Может потому что в $avatar находится путь к изображению, (что на вряд ли) или что там не так. Помогите, пожалуйста, товарищи знатоки.

```
<?php
 session_start();

 include("db-info.php");
 $link = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass);
 if(!mysql_select_db($database)) die(mysql_error());

 include("session.inc.php");
 include("loadsettings.inc.php");
 include ("header.php");

$mailTo = $_GET['mailto'];

// Variables that recieves translations
// To make script untranslated remove $ chars for below vars in script.
$Inbox = Входящие ;
$Compose = Написать ;
$View = Открыть ;
$Delete = Удалить ; 
$Reply = Ответить ;
$Send = Отправить ;
// Variables that recieves translations

?>

<? if ($session == true) { ?>

<table  style="text-align:left;margin-left:50px;">

  <tr>

    <td> 
    <form method="post" action="mymessages.php?mailto=<?php echo $mailTo ?>">   
    <input class="btn_mail_write" type="submit"  name="mailAction" value="Написать" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="btn_mail_inbox" type="submit"  name="mailAction" value="Входящие" />
    </form>
        </td> 
  </tr>
</table>

<?php

    if(!empty($_POST['mailAction']) && isset($_POST['mailAction'])){
        $action = $_POST['mailAction'];
    } else {
        $action = $Inbox;
    }

//$Compose = MSG_Compose_END ;
    if(($action == $Compose) || ($action == $Reply)) {

        if(isset($_POST['mailSubject']) && !empty($_POST['mailSubject'])){
            $mailSubject = 'Re: '.$_POST['mailSubject'];
        } else {
            $mailSubject = "";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['mailFrom']) && !empty($_POST['mailFrom'])){
            $mailTo = $_POST['mailFrom'];
        } else {
            $mailTo = "$mailTo";
        }

// Compose Message Form

        ?>
<table width="100%">
  <tr> 
    <td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
       <td >    
            <form action="mymessages.php" method='post'>
                <div class="area-messages">
                <p><br><b>Кому:</b><input  type='text' name='mailTo' size='50' maxlength="30" value='<?php echo $mailTo; ?>'></p>
                <p><b>Тема:</b><input type='text' name='mailSubject' size='50' maxlength="30" value='<?php echo $mailSubject; ?>'></p>
                <p><textarea class='messagestext'  maxlength='700'  name='mailMessage'></textarea></p>
                <p style="text-align:right;margin-right:15px;"><input class="button" type="submit" name="mailAction" value="Отправить" /></p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </td> 
        <td width="100">&nbsp;</td> 
  </tr>
</table>            
        <?php
       }

    if($action == $Send) {

        if(empty($_POST['mailSubject']) || !isset($_POST['mailSubject'])){

        } else {
            $subject = $_POST['mailSubject'];
        }

        if(empty($_POST['mailTo']) || !isset($_POST['mailTo'])){
        if(strlen($content) < 1){ 
        die("Вы не заполнили получателя!<br> 
        <form name=\"back\" action=\"mymessages.php\" method=\"post\"> 
        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Try Again\"> 
        </form> ");
        }
        } else {
            $mailTo = $_POST['mailTo'];
        }

        if(empty($_POST['mailMessage']) || !isset($_POST['mailMessage'])){
        if(strlen($content) < 1){ 
        die("Вы не заполнили сообщение!<br> 
        <form name=\"back\" action=\"mymessages.php\" method=\"post\"> 
        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Try Again\"> 
        </form> "); 
        }

        } else {
            $message = $_POST['mailMessage'];
        }

        // $date = date('m/d/Y')." at ".date('g:i.s')." ".date('a');
        $date = date('Y-m-d')." / ".date('H:i');
        $userid = $username;
        $q  = "INSERT INTO mail (UserTo, UserFrom, avatar, Subject, Message, SentDate, status) 
                        VALUES ('$mailTo','$userid','$avatar','$subject','$message','$date','<h9>Новое</h9>')";
        if(!($send = mysql_query($q))){
            echo "Сообщение для ".$mailTo." не было отправлено !";
        } else {
echo "<table border='0' width='100%' border='0 cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' class='main'>";
 echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td width='100'>&nbsp;</td>";
  echo "<td>";
            echo "<p>Сообщение для <b>".$mailTo."</b> отправлено !</p>";

    echo "</td> ";
 echo "</tr> ";
echo "</table> ";           
        }

    }

    if($action == $Inbox) {

        $user = $username;
        $q = "SELECT * FROM mail WHERE UserTo = '$user' ORDER BY SentDate DESC";
        $getMail = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($getMail) == 0){
echo "<table width='100%' >";
 echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td width='100'>&nbsp;</td>";
  echo "<td>";  
            echo "<p class='msg'>Писем нет !</p><br/><br/>";
    echo " </td> ";
 echo " </tr> ";
echo "</table> ";           
        } else {            
            ?>
<table width="100%" >
    <tr> 
        <td>            
            <table border="0">
                <tr class="title">

                    <td width="50"><b>От кого</b></b></td>
                    <td width="50"><b>Статус</b></td>
                    <td width="50"><b>Тема</b></td>
                    <td><b>Дата\Время</b></td>
                </tr>

            <?php

            while($mail = mysql_fetch_array($getMail)){ 
        echo "<form action='mymessages.php' method='post'>";

                ?>
                    <tr>

                        <td style="border-top: #999 2px dashed;"><div style="width:50px;"><?php echo $mail['avatar']; ?></div><div style="overflow:hidden;width:100px;"><?php echo $mail['UserFrom']; ?></div></td>
                        <td style="border-top: #999 2px dashed;"><?php echo $mail['status']; ?></td>
                        <td style="border-top: #999 2px dashed;"><div style="overflow:hidden;width:80px;"><h8><?php echo $mail['Subject']; ?></h8></div></td>
                        <td style="border-top: #999 2px dashed;"><h8><?php echo $mail['SentDate']; ?></h8></td>
                        <td align="center"><input class="button" type="submit"  name="mailAction" id="mailAction" value="Удалить" /></td>
                    </tr>
                        <input type="hidden" name="mail_id" value='<?php echo $mail['mail_id']; ?>' />
                        <td align="center" style="padding-bottom:20px;"><input class="button" type="submit"  name="mailAction" id="mailAction" value="Открыть" /></td>

                <?php
                    echo "</form>";

            }

        }           
        echo "</table>";
    echo " </td> ";
 echo " </tr> ";
echo "</table> ";

    }

//$View = MSG_Read_END ;
    if($action == $View) {

        $mail_idx = $_POST['mail_id'];
        $user = $username;
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE UserTo = '$user' AND mail_id = '$mail_idx'") or die ("Действуйте !");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    //  echo $username;

        $Прочитано = "<h8>Прочитано</h8>";
        $q = "UPDATE mail SET status='$Прочитано' WHERE UserTo='$username' AND mail_id='$row[mail_id]'";
        mysql_query($q) or die("Ошибка чтения сообщения !.");

        ?>
<table  width="100%" >
  <tr> 
    <td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
       <td >                    
            <form method="post" action="mymessages.php" >
                <div class="area-messages">
                    <p style="text-align:left;"><b>От кого:</b><?php echo $row['UserFrom']; ?><input type="hidden" name="mailFrom" value="<?php echo $row['UserFrom']; ?>" /></p>
                    <p style="text-align:left;"><b>Тема:</b><?php echo $row['Subject']; ?><input type="hidden" name="mailSubject" value="<?php echo$row['Subject']; ?>" /></p>
                    <p style="text-align:left;"><b>Сообщение:</b><p class='messagesbox'><?php echo $row['Message']; ?></p><br /></p>
                    <p style="text-align:right;padding-right:20px;"><input class="button" type="submit" name="mailAction" value="Ответить" /></p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </td> 
      <td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>            
        <?php
    }

// $Delete = MSG_Delete_END ;   
    if($action == $Delete) {
        $id = $_POST['mail_id'];
        $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM mail WHERE mail_id='$id' LIMIT 1");

        if(!$query) {
            echo "Сообщение не может быть удалено !";
        } else {
            echo "Сообщение удалено !";
        }
    }

?>

<? } 
else { echo"<script language=\"JavaScript\">window.location.href='error.php';</script>";}
?>
```

Comment: Лень качать. Выложите, пожалуйста, проблемный участок кода.

Comment: `$userid = $username;` добавляется никнэйм пользователя, если вписать `$userid = $avatar;` то ничего не добавляется.

Comment: **kostya ** поделись пожалуйста скриптом **личные сообщения**, мне тоже нужно прикрутить на самописный сайт личные сообщения, хотел посмотреть как реализовано, плохо, что здесь нельзя отправлять личные сообщения )

Comment: Честно говоря тот код который я писал это полный бред. Если тебе надо реализовать личные сообщения давай держать связь через почту и мы решим этот вопрос, это не так то уж и сложно. Хорошо если ты понимаешь sql, собственно это здесь основное, так как весь скрипт построен на sql запросах. 

    Homchenkokostya@gmail.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Страшная мешанина кода... Сходу ошибку не определишь. Попробуйте вместо `mysql_query($q);` написать `die($q);` - сообщение не отправится, зато вы сможете отладить запрос.

Comment: А в каком месте вы определяете $avatar ?

Comment: Я извеняюсь за свою ГЛУПОСТЬ и ТУПОСТЬ. У меня этот скрипт стоит инклудом на странице mymessages.php; просто надо было там выставить выборку.

    $r = mysql_query("SELECT avatar FROM `members` WHERE id ='$userid'");
        $row1 = mysql_fetch_row($r);
        $avatar = $row1[0];

[:-)

Comment: Если бы я знал, где это все определяется, я бы нашел бы, где и $avatar определить.

Comment: Ну, если все работает, то ура). Но советую при наличии времени переписать все с нуля - слишком много в скрипте говнокода, особенно связанного с безопасностью:  

    else{
        $message = $_POST['mailMessage'];
    }
    ...
    $q  = "INSERT INTO mail (UserTo, UserFrom, avatar, Subject, Message, SentDate, status) 
           VALUES ('$mailTo','$userid','$avatar','$subject','$message','$date','<h9>Новое</h9>')";

Comment: А какие именно здесь строки, связанные с безопасностью, и что с ними делать?

Answer (score 3):

2 таблицы:

1.members:

```
 - id(идентификационный номер пользователя)
 - name
 - avatar
 - и так далее
```

2.messages:

```
  - id(идент.номер сообщения)
  - sender(идент.номер отправителя из таблицы мемберз(столбец id) )
  - receiver(идент.номер получателя из таблицы мемберз(столбец id) )
  - body(текст сообщения
  - и тд..
```

теперь вынимаем сообщение из базы данных

SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `receiver`='наш получатель'

получаем массив значений id,**sender**,receiver,body..

нам нужен **sender**(отправитель сообщения)

теперь лезем в таблицу пользователя за аватарой, именем и другими данными

SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `id`='$sender'

получили name,avatar и всё остальное что нам нужно

это для входящих, для исходящих думаю понятно что нужно изменить)

**а по поводу**

> А какие именно здесь строки, связанные
> с безопасностью, и что с ними делать?

читайте про sql injection, xss уязивости

Answer (score 2):

А зачем вообще в базу с сообщениями пихать аватар, достаточно по-моему id отправителя, и потом аватар вытаскивать с базы по id. Зачем дублировать информацию?