# Хранение данных

Tags: mysql

Интересует практический вопрос. Где хранятся письма, сообщения на сайтах знакомств, в соц. сетях? В учебниках больше говорится о базах данных. Так ли это? Или более подходящее место в файлах?

Comment: А разве БД - это не файлы?

Comment: Насчёт "файлов" -- это к знаменитому (первый в создании серьёзных веб-приложений) программисту, а ныне бизнесмену П.Грэму http://www.paulgraham.com

Comment: > Так ли это?

Пошутили они)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно же в базе данных, на то и она "база" "данных". Вот рядом в ветке, пользователь как раз хранит сообщения пользователей сайта в базе данных MySQL: [Личные сообщения между пользователями сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/22314/php-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0)

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите вот этот блог http://www.insight-it.ru/highload/ - там очень интересно описана архитектура подобных сервисов - ВК, Однокласники и прочее.

Comment: Весьма познавательная ссылка