# Личные сообщения на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование

Добрый день! Подскажите, как реализовывают функцию общения на сайте, а конкретно проверку новых сообщений? Есть, к примеру, беседа с пользователем, я отправил ему сообщение и какими способами я могу узнать есть ли от него ответ?

Конечно же без фреймов, желательно наименьшая нагрузка на сервер.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для меньшей нагрузки заведите в таблице пользователей поле с количеством сообщений. Когда кто-то написал пользователю делайте в этом поле `+1`. Если `>0` значит сообщения есть, кроме того можно отображать их количество (непрочитанных)

Это будет быстрее чем поиск в таблице ЛС непрочитанных записей с `id` текущего пользователя

Comment: Т. е. при помощи AJAX с каким-то определенным интервалом отправляться запросы? а кто знает как в контакте сделаны real-time уведомления?

Comment: смотря на что ориентирован ваш проект. Возможно в нём вообще не имеет смысла использовать AJAX относительно ЛС.

---

В VK сообщения написаны на nodeJS если не ошибаюсь, а с клиентской стороны AJAX c long-polling

Answer (score 0):

[Задавали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/22314/php-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0) уже такой вопрос, воспользуйтесь поиском.

Comment: Да? прочитайте свою ссылку

Comment: Вы бы корректнее вопрос ставили. Вы можете использовать AJAX-запросы для того, чтобы узнавать о новых событиях, или же long-polling.